# CSS sprite - Moving background for navigation (hover, active, etc) + spaces between elements

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm doing a navigation menu with CSS sprite where instead of uploading a lot of images, you merge them all together and can see hover, active effects by moving background position, i.e. http://www.threestyles.com/tutorials/coding-apples-navigation-bar-using-css-sprites/

**The difference** in my navigation is that I have *spaces* between the navigation elements and I can't find the way how to move the background that it would work nicely.

Elements either popup too close to each other (i.e. no space left between the elements while hovering between them) or the background moves too little/much if I change the properties.

(http://s17.postimage.org/ska9gj065/navprrrob.jpg)

Here's my navigation and sizes:

"Priser" button - width: 100px; 
Space between "Priser" and "Reservere" - 15px. 
"Reservere" - width: 120px;
Space between "Reservere" and "Klub" - 14px. 
"Klub" - width: 100px;

Sorry for not putting all of it to the image.

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li id="list1"><a href="#"><span>Priser</span></a></li>
    <li id="list2"><a href="#"><span>Reservere</span></a></li>
    <li id="list3"><a href="#"><span>Klub</span></a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

**And my CSS:**

```
#nav span {
  display: none;
}

#nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

#nav a {
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
}

#list1 { width: 100px; }
#list2 { width: 130px; }
#list3 { width: 100px; }

#list1 a:hover {
  background: url(images/nav.png) 0px -45px no-repeat;
}

#list2 a:hover {
  background: url(images/nav.png) -115px -45px no-repeat;   
}

#list3 a:hover {
  background: url(images/nav.png) -260px -45px no-repeat;   
}
```

It may not be very easy to understand until you test it but I didn't have where to host it at this moment.

### So, the questions:

1. Is it possible to use this CSS sprite when you have *unused* space between the elements?
2. If it is, what should should be the parameters in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do it. First you have to give your `<li>`-s the exact same width as your background buttons. And then use `margin` to get the desired spacing, i.e.:

```
#list2 { width: 120px; margin-right: 15px; }
```

Comment: Oh god, it was so obvious. How did I miss it.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should give width & height to container having background image & make it display:block same as the image width height(e.g:priser width should be 100)

Comment: By container, you mean, i.e. #list1 a:hover? 
I've tried it - it still does not leave any space between elements when you hover on them. It seems like you need to "push" them somehow more to the right side but I can't figure it out how.

Comment: Actually add background image to <a> & change background position on hover of <a>. Is it possible for you to show the image. A i have used sprites in one of my website( http://www.fabulloso.com/shoes-accessories/shoes/sandals/iteru-red.html) check the sharing icons.

Comment: I just needed some margin, that's it. Thanks anyway.